# Query for Parent Child Relationship to the top level

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
NodeId    NodeName    ParentId   Permission
-----------------------------------------------
1         Node1       0          1
2         Node2       1          NULL
3         Node3       1          NULL
4         Node4       1          NULL
5         Node5       2          NULL
6         Node6       5          NULL
7         Node7       2          NULL
```

I am in Node6 and I need to get the first not NULL permission in the tree (6->5->2->1-> Permission = 1)
How can I do it?

Comment: You really need recursion. What database are you using? Is there a maximum depth to your hierarchy?

Comment: @gbn, SQL Server 2008

Comment: @MartinWilson, there is no maximum depth to the hierarchy.

Comment: Have you tried using a recursive CTE? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: When permission is not NULL, is this the top of the hierarachy? Or is that ParentID = 0?

Comment: @gbn, the top is when ParentId = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `Permission is NOT NULL` must be in the hierarchy, then this row becomes the root node for this case. I've labelled this `RootID` here

Also added more sample data to show multiple branches from the same `ParentID = 0` root

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (NodeId int, NodeName varchar(100), ParentId int, Permission int)
INSERT @t VALUES 
(1,'Node1',0,NULL),
(2,'Node2',1,1),
(3,'Node3',1,NULL),
(4,'Node4',1,NULL),
(5,'Node5',2,NULL),
(6,'Node6',5,NULL),
(7,'Node7',2,NULL),
(8,'Node1',0,NULL),
(9,'Node9',8,2),
(10,'Node10',9,NULL),
(11,'Node11',10,NULL),
(12,'Node12',11,NULL),
(13,'Node13',10,NULL),
(14,'Node14',9,NULL);

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT NodeId, NodeName, ParentId AS RootID FROM @t WHERE Permission IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T.NodeId, T.NodeName, CTE.RootID
    FROM @t T JOIN CTE ON T.ParentId = CTE.NodeId
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    NodeName IN ('Node6', 'Node13');
```